# How to extract a node whose accesstors satisfy some condition?

Tags: xpath

If I use the following xpath,

`//a[@itemprop="email"]/ancestor::li[@itemtype = "http://schema.org/Person"]/ancestor::div[@class="authors__list"]`

I will extract this. But I am interested in only the li with the email. Is there a way to test the ancetors of an `a` is `li` and `div` who has the properties `@itemtype = "http://schema.org/Person` and `@class="authors__list"` respectively? (So that I won't get the li's that do no have emails.) Thanks.

```
<div class="authors__list" data-role="AuthorsList">
                                        <ul class="test-contributor-names">
                                            <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="u-mb-2 u-pt-4 u-pb-4"><span itemprop="name" class="authors__name">Yong&#160;Zhang</span><span class="author-information"><span class="authors__contact"><a href="mailto:zhangy@genomics.cn" title="zhangy@genomics.cn" itemprop="email" data-track="click" data-track-action="Email author" data-track-label=""><img src="/springerlink-static/images/svg/email.svg" height="24" width="24" alt="Email author"></a></span></span></li>
                                            <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="u-mb-2 u-pt-4 u-pb-4"><span itemprop="name" class="authors__name">Qiyuan&#160;Li</span></li>
                                            <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="u-mb-2 u-pt-4 u-pb-4"><span itemprop="name" class="authors__name">Xian&#160;Wang</span></li>
                                            <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="u-mb-2 u-pt-4 u-pb-4"><span itemprop="name" class="authors__name">Xiaolin&#160;Zhou</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Is `//div[@class="authors__list"]/ul/li[@itemtype = "http://schema.org/Person"][descendant::a[@itemprop="email"]]` what you need?

Comment: Yes.  This solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
//a[ancestor::li[@itemtype='http://schema.org/Person']][ancestor::div[@class="authors__list"]]
```

which fits your description of an `a` element with both a `li` and a `div` ancestor, with each ancestor having the specified attribute and attribute value.